# Como centralizar o texto de uma div em JavaScript?

Tags: css

Estou começando agora com JS, criei uma div e queria que o texto dentro dela ficasse sempre ao centro da caixa.
Como posso fazer isso?

Oque eu tenho até agora :

```html
div#CaixaPrincipal{
            
            background: white;
            width: 600px;
            height: 300px;
            margin : 0 auto 0 auto;
            align-items : center;
            font : normal 15pt Arial;
            
        }
```

Comment: Na verdade a linha "align-items" não existe, eu estava testando para ver se alinhava mas não funcionou :/

Comment: Isso não é JavaScript, é CSS.

Comment: Mas esse código é CSS amigo, e não JS rs'

Comment: Apenas adicione `display: flex;` e `justify-content: center;`. Isso já resolve.

Comment: Sem ver seu HTML não da para te responder, o mais provável é que vc está usando a propriedade errada, já que seu container não tem flex, um simples `text-align: center;` deve resolver

Answer (score 0):

Você estava certo em utilizar o `align-items: center`, porém para utilizá-lo você precisa do `display: flex;` também! Então basta fazer o seguinte:

```
div {
     display: flex;
     align-items: center;
     justify-content: center;
}
```

Isso irá centralizar todo o conteúdo da página.

Caso queira manter a distribuição padrão do HTML, você pode direcionar para listar o código por colunas:

```
div {
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: center;
}
```

Se quiser saber mais sobre o *flexbox* vou deixar esse link em PT que fala mais sobre o assunto: https://origamid.com/projetos/flexbox-guia-completo/

Espero que tenha ajudado, abraços!

Comment: Isso centraliza apenas horizontalmente. Como ele diz claramente na pergunta que quer ao centro, teria que centralizar verticalmente também.

Comment: Votei negativo pq a sua resposta não ajuda muito. Só centraliza horizontalmente. E por que usar `flex-direction: column;`? Se melhorar a resposta eu mudo o voto.

Comment: @Sam perdão pelo equivoco, já alterei a resposta.